# DatePicker in XPages can be disabled for editbox but can't be done for the picker button

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I can disable DatePicker in XPages dynamically with disabled="true" by javascript.
However it disables only for the editbox and not for the picker button. The button still work.

How can I also disable the button?

```
    <xp:inputText id="date1"
        defaultValue="#{javascript:@Today()}">
        <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime type="date"
                dateStyle="full">
            </xp:convertDateTime>
        </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:inputText>
```

When disabling,

```
document.getElementById("#{id:date1}").disabled="true";
```

When enabling,

```
document.getElementById("#{id:date1}").disabled="";
```

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your XPages code you have so far.

Comment: I added the codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way is to disable component on server side.

```xml
<xp:button value="disable" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="date1">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.datedisabled = true}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:button value="enable" id="button2">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="date1">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.datedisabled = false}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:inputText id="date1" defaultValue="#{javascript:@Today()}"
    disabled="#{viewScope.datedisabled}">
    <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper2"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="full">
        </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

It includes both: input field and date button. It will always work no matter how the component depending on theme is rendered.

You could still try to accomplish it with client side JavaScript code but I don't recommend it unless you are sure you will never change application's theme.

Comment: Works! Thank for great help!